# Как убрать отображение балунов кластеров в менеджере объектов?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, map, cluster

Как сделать так чтобы на карте использовались кластеры, но при клике на них, они не открывались?
Код на клик:
• manager - objectManager

```
manager.clusters.events.add('click', (e) => {
        let id = e.get('objectId');
        let cluster = manager.clusters.getById(id);
        let geoObjects = cluster.properties.geoObjects;
        this.clusterClick(geoObjects);
        manager.objects.balloon.close();
    });
```

Пробовал сразу по клику закрывать, но это не сработало. Пример взят из официальной документации: [Ссылка на документацию](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/objectManager.Balloon-docpage/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно выставить опцию кластера `hasBalloon: false`, тогда у меток кластеров просто не будет балуна.

```
    objectManager.clusters.options.set('hasBalloon', false);
```

Comment: Если же балун нужен, но не нужно чтобы он открывался то можно сделать так clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: false